# Post 365 records with axios simultaneously

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I have a object of 365 elements like this:

```
data = [ { "a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c", "date": 1663192800000},
{ "a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c", "date": 1663293800000}
{ "a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c", "date": 1643294800000}
...
]
```

I have tried something like this, but the process is slow:

```
 for(var i = 0; i<this.data.length; i++){
          Promise.all([axios.post( "URL",this.data[i])]).then((response) => this.getData())         
        }
```

How can I speed up the sending of data to the db?

Comment: Does the receiving API only take a single item at a time or will it accept more?

Comment: Why dont you want to make 1 post with all the items (entire array) as payload?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to update the backend code with batch insert and send all entries as one request, if possible.

But if this is the only way, First, your code is not efficient because you use `Promise.all` on each element. it would be better to use `map` with the `data` inside the `Promise.all` to resolve altogether.

```
Promise.all(this.data.map(i => axios.post("URL",i)).then((response) => this.getData())
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach is wrong.
You are performing a single request with Promise.all for each array member this way.

`Promise.all` should receive the "already mapped" data as a axios post.

```
// Maps the data array into an array of functions that will return a axios call 

const myPromiseList = this.data.map((thing) =>
    () => axios.post("URL", thing));
Promise.all(myPromiseList)
```